# ImageCropper.forms getting error's

Tags: image, xamarin.forms, cropper

Keep getting this error can't compile because of it, any help?

```
Duplicate Java type found! Mappings between managed types and Java types must be unique. First Type: 'Com.Theartofdev.Edmodo.Cropper.CropImageView+IOnSetImageUriCompleteListenerImplementor, Binding_AndroidImageCropper, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; Second Type: 'Xamarin.Android.ImageCropper.CropImageView+IOnSetImageUriCompleteListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.ImageCropper, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' ParTimers.Android
```

Comment: Have you tried to update your Android support libraries versions?

Comment: Already solve it, it was another package that was conflicting